# How can I call a Django app from another Python app?

Tags: python, django, interface, integration, calling-convention

In the standard setup, Django applications are called by a [WSGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface) server (like [gunicorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gunicorn) and [mod_wsgi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mod_wsgi)) to answer HTTP requests, the entrypoint at user-level is the django View.
Can I make a custom entrypoint to call Django apps? If so, How I properly load a Django app?

**Edit:** Looking at the entrypoint in the [wsgi.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/project_template/project_name/wsgi.py-tpl) file made by the startproject command, I see that 1) it sets the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE var and calls [get_wsgi_application](https://github.com/django/django/blob/b9cf764be62e77b4777b3a75ec256f6209a57671/django/core/wsgi.py) which 2) calls django.setup() and 3) returns a WSGI application that will be called by the WSGI Server. 1 and 2 also happens when django's admin commands are ran. **Is it enough to do 1 and 2 and have a properly loaded Django app?** At 3 the django's middlewares are loaded, but they are not compatible, since I will not be doing HTTP calls (but the Django app will, of course, answer HTTP requests coming from other clients).

Comment: What is the reason behind this question, WSGI is python standard https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3333/

Comment: @iklinac I know that. I need to call Django without using HTTP requests. Gunicorn, for example, does not knows which web framework was used to build the Web apps it calls. The apps just need to offer an entrypoint that is WSGI-compatible. WSGI is an API specification to integrate Python Web Applications with Web Servers allowing Web Apps (and the framework used to implement it) to be independent of Web servers. That integration is done by a WSGI Middleware (the WSGI Server) that receives the HTTP request forwarded by the Web Server, does the properly adaptions and calls the Web app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it enough to do 1 and 2 and have a properly loaded Django app?

Looking at Django's source code and [this documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/applications/), I figured out how to load a Django app. Taking as example the Django's [intro tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/), I could load the polls app and call its [index view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something) this way:

```
# Let Django knows where the project's settings is.
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')

from django.apps import apps
# Load the needed apps
apps.populate(installed_apps=['polls.apps.PollsConfig'])
# Make sure the above apps were loaded
apps.check_apps_ready()
apps.check_models_ready()

# Call it
from polls.views import index
# Here index view is decoupled from Django's HTTP interface, so in polls/views.py you have:
# def index():
#     return Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
print('index view: ' + str(index()))
```

It does not load any of the Django middlewares (they are coupled to the HTTP interface). The polls app does not depends on other installed apps, otherwise all dependencies should be loaded too.